# No such file or directory... Problem with read file using fs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, text, node.js-fs

I have a little problem, I'm trying to read a `.txt` file in node.js app using *fs* library.

My directory tree looks like this:

```bash
app/controller/appController.js
app/data/string.txt
```

My code in appController script looks like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

let data = fs.readFileSync('../data/string.txt', 'utf8');
```

and I'm getting error:

```bash
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../data/string.txt'

 errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '../data/string.txt'
```

Naturally, I've installed fs library.

I was trying conver including fs library to ES module.

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
```

but it doesn't work.

When I've moved .txt file to directory where is appController it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative file paths are resolved with the current working directory for the process, not with the directory of the module your code is in.

You can resolve a path relative to the module directory (in a CommonJS module) by using `__dirname` (which is the current module's path) like this:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../data/string.txt', 'utf8');
```